# Collision detection between spheres of non-zero radius

Tags: java, algorithm, collision-detection, collision, java-3d

I'm making a Java 3D game where you're a ball that jumps on other balls. I have everything figured out except the collision between the player ball and the enemy ball. I have figured out that I could check if the distance between the spheres' centers is less than the sum of their radius, but the problem is that I have no idea how to do so; if anyone knows how I could check the sum of the balls radius I would greatly appreciate you telling me.

Comment: Which part specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem... you have two points in 3D space: the centers of the spheres. You know their radii. So the question is how to compute the distance between 2 points in 3D Euclidean space?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html

Answer (score 0):

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html

See Will's answer here at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/sphere-collision-response#16978

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a container class for the spheres which holds information about them:

```
private class Sphere{
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
        public float radius;
    }
```

Now you have to use the Pythagorean theorem for a 3D space to calculate the distance between the centers of two spheres:

```
public boolean areColiding(Sphere s1, Sphere s2){
        float dist = (float) Math.sqrt((s1.x - s2.x) * (s1.x - s2.x) +
                                       (s1.y - s2.y) * (s1.y - s2.y) +
                                       (s1.z - s2.z) * (s1.z - s2.z));
        if(dist <= s1.radius + s2.radius) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```